# How to signal Spring that Bean property must be populated?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, javabeans

Let's say that I have a Java class like this:

```
public class PersonGrabber {
  private PersonDAO dao;

  public void setDao(PersonDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }
  public PersonDAO getDao() {
    return this.dao;
  }
  //...
}
```

And I have a corresponding Spring bean like this:

```
<bean id="personGrabber" class="com.stackoverflow.example.PersonGrabber">
  <property name="dao"><null/></property>
</bean>
```

Now, this is bad because I really need the `dao` property to be set to something on that bean before it becomes useful. However, I don't wanna wait till runtime to wait for it to throw a `NullPointerException`. Is there anyway to tell Spring that a bean property **MUST** be populated before it can be used? Ideally, I'd like it to crash on initialization so that I don't have to wait for it to find out.

I was hoping for something like an annotation along the lines of:

```
public class PersonGrabber {
  @SpringRequired
  private PersonDAO dao;
  //...
}
```

Any help from some Spring veterans out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the type of class you've got, where you *always* need the other property set to a non-null value, the easiest way of enforcing this is as a two-fold thing. Use the `@Required` annotation on the setter to tell Spring that the method always has to be called, and a check inside the setter to see if the injection is of a real instance (i.e., isn't null).

```
@Required
public void setDao(PersonDao dao) {
    if (dao == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("property 'dao' is null");
    this.dao = dao;
}
```

The final little part is you need to ensure that annotation processing is switched on with this in your Spring config file(s):

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Mind you, there's a good chance you've already got that.

Comment: The other thing to note is that your in-setter validation code can't check anything about the other bean, as that might not be fully configured at the point when this is called. That doesn't matter for a non-null check.

Answer (score 3):

The annotation you are looking for is [@Required](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-required-annotation)

You can also use the [init-method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean) attribute on your bean to point to a method that is called after all properties are populated. This will allow you perform post setup validation.

Comment: But `@Required` is only a part of the solution; it doesn't prevent the configuration from being explicitly `null`.

Comment: My preference is to use init-method rather than annotations. Annotations and the InitializingBean interface introduce a direct dependency on Spring in the application. I avoid that whereever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to do this is to declare the bean class as implementing `InitializingBean`, and implement the `afterPropertiesSet` method to check that the property has been set to an acceptable value.

Answer (score 0):

What about using JSR 303 validation with spring.? Did you have some problem with that.?

Link [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#validation-mvc-configuring), In case if you have not seen it before.

Comment: I actually ended up writing my own Spring Bean Post Processor that used Hibernate's implementation of JSR 303 so that I could put annotations like `@NotNull` on them.